# How to get rid of 'new' to instantiate Ruby objects?

Tags: ruby

Just for cosmetic reasons, I'd like to provide a syntax for object instantiation from some of my classes, without the keyword 'new'. I never tried that, but I know it possible : for instance Matrix gem provides a syntax like :

```
Matrix [ [1,2], [3,4] ]
```

How could I do the same ?

Comment: You might also want to correct `instanciate` => `instantiate`.

Comment: @sawa: oh, you have enough rep to correct a typo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overload `self.[]`:

```
class Foo
    attr_accessor :bar

    def initialize(bar)
        self.bar=bar
    end

    def self.[](*args)
        return Foo.new(*args)
    end
end

puts Foo[1].bar
```

Answer (score 7):

Just define a method with the same name (that of a class) that will invoke `.new`.

```
class User
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  attr_reader :name
end

def User(name)
  User.new(name)
end

u = User("Sergio")
u.name # => "Sergio"
```

**NOTE:** I personally don't like this technique. Leads to harder to understand code. The "just looks better" reason does not excuse you to use this.

**Actually**, it's a pattern in ruby, called "conversion method". If you look closer, all of the upper-case methods in ruby stdlib are converting values from one form to another. Unless you're writing a conversion method, don't do this.

- [Kernel#Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array)
- [Kernel#Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash)
- and so on...

Comment: Is it better to define it on `Kernel`?

Comment: @sawa: For simplicity I decided to define it on top level (and, therefore, on every object). But yeah, generally you'd want to mix it into Kernel or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

> Just for cosmetic reasons, I'd like to provide a syntax for object instantiation from some of my classes, without the keyword 'new'.

`new` isn't a keyword. It's a method just like any other method. And you don't have to call it `new`, you can call it anything you like. For example, you can call it `call`:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(val)
    puts "Initialized with #{val}!"
  end

  class << self; alias_method :call, :new end
end

foo = Foo.(42)
# Initialized with 42!
```

In Ruby, implementing `call` is equivalent to saying "this is a function". Anything which implements `call` is basically a function or can be treated as one. And if you think of `Class`es as factory functions for objects, then it even makes sense to do this.

If you think of `Class`es as functions, then you should also implement `to_proc` so that you can use them in place of blocks:

```
class << Foo
  def to_proc
    -> var { new(var) }
  end
end

[23, 42].map(&Foo)
# Initialized with 23!
# Initialized with 42!
# => [#<Foo:0xdeadbeef081523>, #<Foo:0xdeadbeef081542>]
```

In fact, you could do it globally:

```
class Class
  alias_method :call, :new

  def to_proc
    -> (*args, &block) { new(*args, &block) }
  end
end
```

Or you can call your factory method `[]`:

```
class << Foo; alias_method :[], :new end

foo = Foo[42]
# Initialized with 42!
```

In fact, this latter one is common practice for anything collection-like: `Array` and `Hash` from the core library, `Set`, `SortedSet` and `Matrix` from the standard library have such factory methods.

Another possibility is to define a method on `Kernel` with the same name as your class:

```
module Kernel
  private

  def Foo(obj)
    Foo.new(obj)
  end
end

Foo(42)
# Initialized with 42!
```

Note, however, that this pattern is usually reserved for conversion methods that convert an object to an object of a different class unless that object is already of that class (see `Kernel#Array`, `Kernel#Integer` etc. for examples).

So, you would rather implement it like this (if at all):

```
module Kernel
  private

  def Foo(obj)
    return obj if obj.is_a?(Foo)

    begin
      return obj.to_foo
    rescue NoMethodError => e
      return Foo.new(obj) if e.name == 'to_foo'
      raise
    end
  end
end

Foo(42)
# Initialized with 42!
```